# Extract malicious code from PDF file

Tags: malware, javascript, pdf

I've a PDF file that contains some malicious code; when opened the processor usage maxes out and the fans run at full rpm. The [`pdfid.py`](https://blog.didierstevens.com/programs/pdf-tools/) produces the following output:

```
PDF Header: %PDF-1.7
 obj                 8598
 endobj              8598
 stream              8001
 endstream           8001
 xref                   0
 trailer                0
 startxref              2
 /Page                594
 /Encrypt               0
 /ObjStm              981
 /JS                    1
 /JavaScript            0
 /AA                    2
 /OpenAction            1
 /AcroForm              0
 /JBIG2Decode           0
 /RichMedia             0
 /Launch                0
 /EmbeddedFile          0
 /XFA                   0
 /URI                   0
 /Colors > 2^24         0
```

`/JS` indicate that there's one JavaScript code and `/AA` and `/OpenAction` indicate that there are code which will launch the JavaScript code.

However using the [`pdf-parser.py`](https://blog.didierstevens.com/programs/pdf-tools/) tool, searching for keyword `javascript` produces no matches:

```
python ./pdf-parser.py --search javascript ./document.pdf
```

But searching for keyword `OpenScript` returns one match.

```
python ./pdf-parser.py --search openaction --raw ./document.pdf
```

result:

```
obj 33412 0
 Type: /Catalog
 Referencing: 37640 0 R, 4364 0 R, 37641 0 R, 33413 0 R, 18188 0 R, 33259 0 R, 33264 0 R, 18275 0 R, 37642 0 R
<</MarkInfo 37640 0 R/Metadata 4364 0 R/Names 37641 0 R/OpenAction 33413 0 R/Outlines 18188 0 R/PageLabels 33259 0 R/PageLayout/SinglePage/PageMode/UseNone/Pages 33264 0 R/StructTreeRoot 18275 0 R/Type/Catalog/ViewerPreferences 37642 0 R>>

  <<
    /MarkInfo 37640 0 R
    /Metadata 4364 0 R
    /Names 37641 0 R
    /OpenAction 33413 0 R
    /Outlines 18188 0 R
    /PageLabels 33259 0 R
    /PageLayout /SinglePage
    /PageMode /UseNone
    /Pages 33264 0 R
    /StructTreeRoot 18275 0 R
    /Type /Catalog
    /ViewerPreferences 37642 0 R
  >>
```

Executing:

```
python ./pdf-parser.py --reference 33412 --raw ../document.pdf
```

result:

```
obj 37639 0
 Type: /XRef
 Referencing: 33410 0 R, 33412 0 R
 Contains stream

  <<
    /DecodeParms
      <<
        /Columns 5
        /Predictor 12
      >>
    /Filter /FlateDecode
    /ID [<0B1CC64D68284D90BD0A295FADB0972A><08CB936A1AF9EB42A906D26EC2F80EFA>]
    /Index [33411 15558]
    /Info 33410 0 R
    /Length 7901
    /Prev 15523287
    /Root 33412 0 R
    /Size 48969
    /Type /XRef
    /W [1 3 1]
  >>


obj 4368 0
 Type: /XRef
 Referencing: 33410 0 R, 33412 0 R
 Contains stream

  <<
    /DecodeParms
      <<
        /Columns 5
        /Predictor 12
      >>
    /Filter /FlateDecode
    /ID [<0B1CC64D68284D90BD0A295FADB0972A><08CB936A1AF9EB42A906D26EC2F80EFA>]
    /Info 33410 0 R
    /Length 8135
    /Root 33412 0 R
    /Size 33411
    /Type /XRef
    /W [1 3 1]
  >>
```

Finally running

```
python ./pdf-parser.py --object 4368 --raw --filter ./document.pdf
```

produces a binary output that I cannot decompress.

**Can someone please point out my mistake or tell me how to extract the JavaScript and OpenAction code for viewing?**

Comment: A stream is compressed (`--raw` ) . You can dump the decompressed object indeed, check out this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27997930/how-to-decode-a-pdf-stream

Comment: Well, that's mean you are not getting the first javascript entry point, but part of the obfuscated payload.  My suggestion : download the GUI PDF dissector and use it to learn how the malicious PDF is structured.

Comment: Have you tried to just open the pdf files in a text editor? If I recall correctly, you should be able to see the javascript as plaintext.

Comment: It seems peedft  give you a nice walk through.  Please use the similar method than immediately jump into the object that you found, which may not be the script. (Btw, I just notice the pdfdissector removed by the author, somebody mentioned they join google ).

Comment: `pdfinfo -js myfile.pdf` prints all JavaScript in the PDF. `pdfinfo` is from Poppler.

Answer (score 1):

Use any [Hex Editor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hex_editor), to split open the contents of the PDF file(aka image, text, javascript code etc). You can validate your file's contents henceforth and filter the javascript or suspicious code.

Comment: "Use a hex editor" doesn't seem like much of an answer, and you offer no explanation as to how someone would "validate their file's contents" or "filter the javascript"

Answer (score 0):

You could also use pdfstreamdumper and use "Search_For" in the top menu for JavaScript.

If you find the Object ID you need with pdf-parser.py, you could also just go straight to that in the left column of pdfstreamdumper as well.